# The transaction ends successfully but in the contract remains pend forever!

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, ethers.js

```
  const id = Number(globalChainId)
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
  const signer = provider.getSigner()
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer)
  const { chainId } = await provider.getNetwork()

  if (chainId != id) {
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
        params: [{ chainId: `0x${id.toString(16)}` }],
      })
    } catch {
      await window.ethereum.request({
        method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
        params: [
          {
            chainId: `0x${id.toString(16)}`,
            chainName: 'Polygon Mainnet',
            rpcUrls: ['https://polygon-rpc.com'],
            nativeCurrency: {
              name: 'Matic',
              symbol: 'MATIC',
              decimals: 18,
            },
            blockExplorerUrls: ['https://polygonscan.com/'],
          },
        ],
      })
    }
  }

  const transactionHash = await contract.transfer(
    TRANSFER_ADDRESS,
    amount * 1e2,
    { gasLimit: 200000 },
  )
  
  await transactionHash.wait()
```

Comment: Sounds like your gas price (not limit) is too low. What is it, and what does polygon gas tracker suggest?